# Spline from Object" in Animation Nodes?

Tags: modeling, animation-nodes

I'm trying to get this result (picture in this post). Anyway, I created a Bezier circle, but I can't find the "Spline from Object" node neither the "Combine Mesh Data". I guess I miss something but I can't see it.

Does someone could help me to get this ?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the post and make the title more descriptive please? Something like *"Spline from Object" in Animation Nodes*?

Comment: Hello, what version are you using ? Make sure you have the latest : https://animation-nodes.com/#download Also, the nodes are called "Spline**S** from Object" and "Combine Mesh" now

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found. The menu is called "Get from object" in "curve" menu. This displays the "spline from object" node....

Anyway, the final result is not working for me. If someone can help me with a tuto, I could appreciate.

I edit:

The problem is fixed:

- First, the "combine mesh data" node is "combine mesh" now.
- Second, in the "Mesh Data Output"node, if you look for the "target" object, you'll not find it. You have to click on the "+" icon.
- Last, in the "Mesh Data Output" node again, don't forget to click on the button that becomes blue in front of "MeshData". And it works.

Comment: Hello, you are mistaking bezier curves (geometry) with fcurves (animation data)